# convert time format on a whole file

Tags: datetime, date

I have a file with 20,000 dates in it that I need to convert and save back to a file. The dates are the only thing in the file and they are on separate lines.

This is what they are not

```
2011-01-03T16:44:09Z
```

and this is what I need

```
2011-01-03 12:34:00
```

Comment: doesn't matter, just going to process the file and then done with it.

Comment: What is this format `2011-01-03T16:44:09Z`?

Comment: It is very easy if you know how to convert T16:44:09Z to 12:34:00

Comment: i don't and that is why I asked.

Comment: Do you have access to a spreadsheet?

Comment: And what timezone do you want the dates to be from?

Comment: =TEXT((SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"Z"," "),"T"," "))-(5/24),"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS")

put this in the column B, copy the range and paste the *values* into a new sheet and save it as text.

EDIT: Rather subtract 5/24ths.

Comment: I learnt and did it for you :) But if you can do it on excel that is better.

Comment: in c# user XmlConvert.ToDateTime(line).ToString();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Ruby in your system, you can create a file like this:

**date_parser.rb**

---

```
require "date"

new_dates = File.open("new_dates.txt","w")

File.open("old_dates.txt","r") do |f| 
  while line = f.gets
    newdate = DateTime.parse(line)
    new_dates << newdate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") << "\n"
  end
end

new_dates.close
```

---

Then you just run

**$ ruby date_parser.rb**

All you new dates will be in "**new_dates.txt**"
This script assumes you have a file "**old_dates.txt**" with *each date in a different line*.

Comment: Would DateTime.parse parse the format which the OP has given?

Comment: this only does the first date in the file

Answer (score 1):

In Excel, FTW.

=TEXT((SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"Z"," "),"T"," "))-(5/24),"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS")

Answer (score 0):

Christian is right, but i think u need lower case "date"

`require "date"`